# WCF 4 REST - How to gain full control over the messages sent

Tags: .net, wcf, rest

**Background:**
I am currently using the Visual Studio 2010 online template "WCF REST Service Template 40(CS)" and it works great for my primarily JSON based service. I've even got it working to return a stream when returning an image.

**Scenario:**
I am currently looking into the server push & multipart/x-mixed-replace technology to replace the polling for images method I am currently using.

**The Problem:**
The issue I am facing is that I am unable to find a way to get FULL control of every byte that is sent out on the wire, and this is causing me to be unsuccessful in properly implementing the multipart/x-mixed-replace mechanism. This REST service is automatically putting in the http version, content-length, etc automatically when i would rather have full control of everything that goes on the wire in this particular instance.

Any help would be much appreciated. The server push tech seems so cool!

Answer (score 0):

When you are using WCF 4 REST templates, than it will be easy for you to convert to [ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api) former WCF Web API, there you can gain control over messages.

You can also intercept messages using standart mechanism for WCF of message interception using  IDispatchMessageInspector.

Or you can use streaming to upload to server your bytes in stream (for example http://blogs.msdn.com/b/endpoint/archive/2010/11/24/streaming-over-http-with-wcf.aspx)
Read your bytes from stream. It will be easy.